# How to Install xcode.app via terminal only (without using GUI)

Tags: xcode, macos

**The goal:** is to automate the macOS app notarization using Amazon EC2 with the Jenkins pipeline.

**Problem statement:**
The EC2 macOS AMIs only has the Xcode command-line tool preinstalled in those AMIs, I can't install the `Xcode.app` via ssh/command line onto the EC2 machine. To install the Xcode, it has to be via the Apple App Store, using the GUI to log in first. The `Xcode.app` is required for the notarization.

**Attempts / Experimented**

I have tried the `mas cli` which is no longer to support sign in from the command line. https://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/use-the-mac-app-store-from-the-command-line

> In macOS High Sierra (10.13) Apple removed the -[ISAccountService
> signInWithContext:replyBlock:] method from the StoreFoundation private
> Apple framework which this app relies on to authenticate users through
> the signin command. I have done a lot of digging and debugging but
> have not found another API that works to authenticate a user with the
> Mac App Store.
>
> Users running older macOS versions (10.9-10.12) are unaffected.

You need to have xcode.app for not notarization https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126350
The documentation seems clear enough:

> "Prepare Your Software for Notarization Notarization requires Xcode 10
> or later. Building a new app for notarization requires macOS 10.13.6
> or later. Stapling an app requires macOS 10.12 or later."

It seems the 'altool' is used for the notarization for xcode12. I tried to copy the altool from my dev machine to the Jenkins machine `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` and got this error when running it.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/altool
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      xcrun altool
```

Even the `otool -L` doesn't show the `altool` has any linkage with the xcode.

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/altool:
@rpath/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
@rpath/AppStoreService.framework/Versions/A/AppStoreService (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1122.24.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1775.109.0)
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.100.5)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1775.109.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 59754.100.88)
```

Comment: Why do you need whole Xcode? Use the "notarytool" which is bundled in Xcode. Place it on some server - download it from there.

Comment: @MarekH If I understand you correctly, the notarytool is bundled in Xcode13 only, not in the Xcode12. and you think/know that I can just copy that notarytool from one machine to another? and then just use that?

Comment: The documentation seems clear enough: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution

"Prepare Your Software for Notarization

Notarization requires Xcode 10 or later. Building a new app for notarization requires macOS 10.13.6 or later. Stapling an app requires macOS 10.12 or later."

Comment: "otool -l" doesn't show any linkage to Xcode. ./notarytool history --keychain-profile xxxx works even with xcode-select pointed to xcode12. I haven't run any tests. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow

Comment: this tool might help https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/xcodes

Answer (score 1):

[xcode-install](https://github.com/xcpretty/xcode-install) is a nifty tool to install, update, and manage Xcode versions on the command line. Works great with automation tools like Ansible, too. It downloads Xcode, simulators from the Apple Developer Portal using [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/). This means you need an ADP account.

Installation:

```
$ gem install xcode-install
```

You also need to set the environment variables `XCODE_INSTALL_USER` and
`XCODE_INSTALL_PASSWORD` (use your ADP login). If your ADP account does not have 2FA enabled, you need to set `SPACESHIP_SKIP_2FA_UPGRADE=1`, too. If your ADP account has 2FA enabled, please see [this issue](https://github.com/xcpretty/xcode-install/issues/395).

```
$ xcversion list
```

lists all available Xcode versions. To install, for example, 13.2.1, run:

```
$ xcversion install 13.2.1
```

Ensure that you have at least 30 GB of free disk space. Otherwise the decompression of the Xcode archive fails. If you need to increase the size of your EBS volume, see [this article in the AWS documentation on how to do it on a Mac](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-mac-instances.html#mac-instance-increase-volume).

Of course, it is also possible to use Screen Sharing (VNC) to install Xcode via the GUI. [To enable Screen Sharing on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-mac-instances.html#mac-instance-vnc):

1. Set a user password if you haven't already:

   ```
   $ sudo passwd ec2-user
   ```
2. Enable Screen Sharing:

   ```
   $ sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart \
     -activate -configure -access -on \
     -restart -agent -privs -all
   ```
3. Start an SSH tunnel **on your local computer**:

   ```
   $ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@my-instance-public-dns-name
   ```
4. Connect to your AWS Mac with *Screen Sharing.app* from your local computer by connecting to `localhost:5900`.

Comment: I use "xcodes" tool to manage multiple xcode version. It works good, but I don't find any solution for this f@#ing apple 2FA. It is forcelly enabled and there is no way do disable it. I have no idea how ppl automate setupping apps on macos with ansible and avoide the SMS codes from apple 2FA.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote xcodeinstall to facilitate automatic download and install in cloud (AWS) scneario. It optionally integrates with AWS Secrets Manager. This allows you to securely store your authentication credentials in the cloud. Once done, you can signin in one machine (and enter MFA code) to generate a session token and download / install on other machines sharing the same cloud account.

Give it a try and share your feedback
https://github.com/sebsto/xcodeinstall

Comment: This!! Thank you so much for creating this! Really, really smooth and fixed my issues on the AWS Mac!